# Can I use my 16000mAh power bank with 5V 2.1A output to power my laptop (laptops battery says 11.1V, 5225mAh), or will this end in disaster?

Tags: batteries

Like title says, I have a 16000mAh power bank I'd like to use to keep my laptop going (cushy security guard job, work nights). As far as I can tell, it appears to be intended for use with cell phones and tablets- however, I'm pretty sure I can get an adapter for it to hook it up to my laptop (from one of the power bank's usb ports). Would I risk frying something by doing so? My laptop's battery says 11.1V and 5225mAh. The laptop is a hp envy.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that without heavily modifying your power bank, i.e. keeping only the battery and a little more.

Your power bank has a huge battery inside, some protection circuit, a voltage regulator to provide the clean 5V output and a charging circuit that recharges your battery.
Your laptop needs 11.1V so you will need to replace the voltage regulator with something that has an output of 11.1V or so.
Moreover I bet your laptop consumes more than \$5V\cdot 2.1A = 10.5W\$ so your power bank might not be powerful enough to even turn it on.
The 16Ah you refer to are just a measure of how much *energy* the power bank stores, not how much *power* it can source in any given moment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vladimir, and chances are you will get better results with a different, better suited power source. In time: is your laptop running out of batteries? I cannot help asking about this because you actually did not mention what is the reason you want to use the power bank for and how do you want to connect it to your laptop. Would you be interested on replacing the laptop's original battery for the bank itself?
Cheers.

(PS - I tried to add a comment, but I was not allowed to. Also, since the answer might imply the design of, say, a step-up switched power supply, I saw no problems answering. But I'm the new guy here, sorry.)

Comment: If you need clarification, use the comment to the question, the Answer area is for substantive answers, not "I Agree" nor for clarification.

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly just playing around with visual studio which doesn't seem to be very power intensive, but the most I get is four hours or so. I was hoping to plug the power bank into the laptop's power port for more battery time, but I guess this won't be possible.

Comment: that might be possible, more information are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your external power source will need to supply the same voltage and current as the laptop's normal power supply.

For my Dell laptop, the external supply is rated at 19.5 votls, 4.6 amps, although the battery is only 11.1 volts.

The 5 volts from your battery pack definitely won't do to keep your laptop running, without serious surgery on the battery pack.